# There is no error on input, but no output

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement, output, java.util.scanner

```
   package gradrequirment;
   import java.util.Scanner;
  public class graduation {
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

this programs shows if you can graduate or not from high school..

```
Scanner gpa = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner math_credit = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner english_credit = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner science_credit = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner socialstudies_credit = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner service_hours = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner physed3 = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner arts3 = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean physed;
boolean art;
boolean hope1;
boolean art1;
```

Could it be possible that the char input i tried dosent work?

```
System.out.println("Enter your GPA, service hours, and credits for each class.");
System.out.println("");
System.out.println("Enter GPA:");
double GPA = gpa.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Enter Service Hours:");
int hours = service_hours.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter Y/N if you have take HOPE.");
char hope = physed3.next().charAt(0);
System.out.println("Enter in How Many Math Credits You Have:");
int math = math_credit.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter in English Credits:");
int english = english_credit.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter in Science Credits:");
int science = science_credit.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter in Social Studies Credits:");
int studies = socialstudies_credit.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter Y/N if You Have A Fine Art Credit.");
char arts = arts3.next().charAt(0);
```

all of the booleans  and if-elses seem to function correctly.

```
if (math >= 4)
{
 boolean math1 = true;
}


 else {

  boolean math1 = false;


if (english >= 4)
{
    boolean english1 = true;
}

else {
    boolean english1 = false;


if (science >= 3)
{

boolean science1 = true;
}
else {
    boolean science1 = false;


   if (studies >= 3)
  {
   boolean studies1 = true;
   }
    else {
    boolean studies1 = false;


if (hours >= 100)
{
boolean hours1 = true;
}
else {
    boolean hours1 = false;


    if (GPA >= 2.0)
    {
        boolean gpa1 = true;
    }
    else {
    boolean gpa1 = false;

    if (physed3.next().charAt(0) == (89))
      physed = true;

    else {
    physed = false;

    if (arts3.next().charAt(0) == (89))
        art = true;
    else {
        art = false;


    if (physed == true)
        {
        hope1 = true;
        }
        else {

        hope1 = false;
        }


        if (art == true)
        {
        art1 = true;
        }
        else {

        art1 = false;
```

there is no visible error with the last if else statement, yet there is no output.

```
        if(art1 && hope1 && gpa1 && hours1 && gpa1 && studies1 && science1 && english1 && math1 == true)
        System.out.println("You Have Graduated!");

        else
        System.out.println("You Have Not Graduated. Try Harder!");

    gpa.close();
    math_credit.close();
    science_credit.close();
    socialstudies_credit.close();
    english_credit.close();
    service_hours.close();






        {
        }   
        }

        }
        }
    }
}   
}
}
}
 }  
}
}
```

I am relatively new to java, so i do not know if there is an obvious mistake.

Comment: You can any of the below answers if it solves your problem. Please check the link - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

The main problem you are facing is in the if else contruct. You will never get a output if the value of math(your input from the scanner) is >= 4. Because you are print the output in the else block. Similarly even if your math is <= 4 still your statement will not get executed as you are printing the output inside else block of `if (physed3.next().charAt(0) == (89))`. So you will never get an output until you fail all the conditions of if block till `if (art == true)`. So it seems your if else construct is wrong. So the below block is not at all executing.

```
 if(art1 && hope1 && gpa1 && hours1 && gpa1 
        && studies1 && science1 && english1 && math1 == true)
      System.out.println("You Have Graduated!");

 else
      System.out.println("You Have Not Graduated. Try Harder!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition

```
if(art1 && hope1 && gpa1 && hours1 && gpa1 && studies1 && science1 && english1 && math1 == true)
```

is always `false`. This is why you can't get your output

Answer (score -1):

I modify your program and make it simple. Now it is showing the proper result.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        boolean physed,art,hope1,art1,gpa1,hours1,studies1,science1,english1,math1;

        System.out.println("Enter your GPA, service hours, and credits for each class.");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Enter GPA:");
        double GPA = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter Service Hours:");
        int hours = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Y/N if you have take HOPE.");
        char hope = input.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("Enter Y/N if You Have A Fine Art Credit.");
        char arts = input.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("Enter in How Many Math Credits You Have:");
        int math = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter in English Credits:");
        int english = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter in Science Credits:");
        int science = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter in Social Studies Credits:");
        int studies = input.nextInt();


        if (math >= 4)
            math1 = true;
        else 
            math1 = false;

        if (english >= 4)
            english1 = true;
        else 
            english1 = false;

        if (science >= 3)
            science1 = true;
        else
            science1 = false;

        if (studies >= 3)
            studies1 = true;
        else 
            studies1 = false;

        if (hours >= 100)
            hours1 = true;
        else 
            hours1 = false;

        if (GPA >= 2.0)
            gpa1 = true;
        else 
            gpa1 = false;

        if (hope == 'Y')
              physed = true;
        else 
            physed = false;

        if (arts == 'Y')
            art = true;
        else 
            art = false;

        if (physed == true)
            hope1 = true;
        else 
            hope1 = false;

        if (art == true)
            art1 = true;
        else 
            art1 = false;

        if(art1 && hope1 && gpa1 && hours1 && gpa1 && studies1 && science1 && english1 && math1 == true)
            System.out.println("You Have Graduated!");

        else
            System.out.println("You Have Not Graduated. Try Harder!");
}
```

I have changed the type of variables to boolean and then remove extra statements from your project.